How to improve queries format
I have this query:
UPDATE MY_TABLESET ENDTIME = COALESCE(:ENDTIME, ENDTIME),
    ELAPSEDTIME = EXTRACT(DAY FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME) || 'd '
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME), 'FM00') || ':'
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME), 'FM00') || ':'
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME), 'FM00.000000')
WHERE MISSIONID = :MISSIONID

But I'm trying to get better at structuring them.
Recently we have a "problem" at our team where we have to spend a lot of time redoing queries because they were really bad written and difficult to understand. So, as a personal objective I'm trying to get better.
For this example I want to try to do something like this:
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET ENDTIME = COALESCE(:ENDTIME, ENDTIME),
    TIMEDIFFERENCE = :ENDTIME - STARTTIME,
    ELAPSEDTIME = EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMEDIFFERENCE ) || 'd ' || TO_CHAR(
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMEDIFFERENCE ), 'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR(
        EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFFERENCE ), 'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR(
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFFERENCE ), 'FM00.000000')
WHERE MISSIONID = :MISSIONID

I'm asking for this but any tip or idea are really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Are all of your problem queries like the example? If so, are you able to create a PL/SQL function that can hide the logic?

That's a formatting issue.

one option is to do that manually, but - nowadays, nobody does that because ...

... I believe everyone uses some GUI tool (such as Oracle SQL Developer, TOAD and similar) that offers formatting (which would be the 2nd option)

in TOAD, you'd press [CTRL + SHIFT + F]
in Oracle SQL Developer, that's [CTRL + F7]


you can adjust formatting options, if you want, e.g.



I don't know whether you can make them format code exactly as your example shows, but I guess that - even if you use default formatting options - it would look OK

note that everyone in a team should have the same tool and same formatting options; otherwise, the result won't be the same

finally, the 3rd option I can think of is one of (free) online formatters. It requires you to copy/paste code, format it, and copy/paste back which is kind of annoying. Plus, I'm not sure that you'd want to put all of your code online, just to format it (and possibly risk that someone sees what you don't want to expose to public).



What about adding the "TIMEDIFFERENCE" variable? What about things like that so it is more readable


What about adding the TIMEDIFFERENCE variable? What about things like that so it is more readable

You cannot create an alias in an UPDATE statement.
You can in a SELECT statement so if you use MERGE rather than UPDATE:
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  SELECT :endtime AS endtime,
         :endtime - starttime AS timedifference
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  missionid = :missionid
  AND    :endtime IS NOT NULL
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET endtime     = src.endtime,
      elapsedtime = EXTRACT(DAY FROM src.timedifference )
                    || 'd '
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM src.timedifference ), 'FM00')
                    || ':'
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM src.timedifference ), 'FM00')
                    || ':' 
                    || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM src.timedifference ), 'FM00.000000')

fiddle
